# prioritize listener for cloud firestore query

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I use the following listeners in my Flutter App and they work perfectly fine on their own.

```
Firestore.instance
.collection('talks')
.where("topic", isEqualTo: "flutter")
.snapshots()
.listen((data) =>
    data.documents.forEach((doc) => print(doc["title"])));
```

In my App, I run more of them but if I do that I have to ensure, that one of them always checks for changes before the other one does because the data from the second one depends on it.

Is there any way to do this or do I have to replace the first listener with a normal `.get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
    })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server sends changes to each listener as they are made to the data that the listener monitors. There is no prioritization between listeners, so you will need to do any synchronization between them in your application code.